# SQL Server - Return sets with repeating values in sequential records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have data that looks like the following:
The data is ordered by processID, then by step start date.
Step start date determines the sequence of the steps.
Each step is approved by an approver (the approver ID's below are arbitrary)

```
╔═══════════╦══════════════════════════╦═══════════════╦════════════╗
║ ProcessID ║         StepName         ║Step Start Date║ ApproverID ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════╣
║         1 ║ Supervisor Approval      ║1/1/2013 07:24 ║ A          ║
║         1 ║ Sales Manager Approval   ║1/1/2013 13:35 ║ B          ║
║         1 ║ General Manager Approval ║1/3/2013 08:00 ║ B          ║
║         1 ║ CEO Approval             ║1/5/2013 14:40 ║ C          ║
║         2 ║ Supervisor Approval      ║1/2/2013 07:00 ║ A          ║
║         2 ║ Sales Manager Approval   ║1/2/2013 08:00 ║ B          ║
║         2 ║ General Manager Approval ║1/2/2013 09:00 ║ C          ║
║         2 ║ CEO Approval             ║1/2/2013 10:00 ║ B          ║
╚═══════════╩══════════════════════════╩═══════════════╩════════════╝
```

I need a TSQL query that would return the [ProcessID]'s for any process that has the same ApproverID in 2 or more consecutive steps.

So in the example above, ProcessID #1 would be returned because Approver B approved steps 2 and 3 (consecutively).  ProcessID #2 would not be returned because even though Approver B approved steps 2 and 4, they were not consecutive.

Here is a SQL fiddle with the schema setup and some sample data: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/48589/1)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are we supposed to know the sequence for the steps??

Comment: Have you tried writing a query?

Comment: The sequence of the steps is already set in the result set above.  They were ordered by the date the step started.  Unfortunately, there is no numerical ID or anything like that which maps a step name to a sequence id.  A datetime column could be included which is the date the step started (which is how the data is currently ordered).

Comment: I added the step start date to the date set above.

Comment: I have tried writing - but am having trouble determining an approach.  I could do this very inefficiently by determining which processes have an approver on more than one step, then for each of those, looping through each step and checking if the approver of the current step is the same as that of the last step.  But I was looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns Process 1 as required from your dataset:

```
with nextSteps as
(
  select s.ProcessID
    , disapprove = case when s.ApproverID <= n.ApproverID or n.ApproverID is null
      then 0 else 1 end
  from steps s
    outer apply
    (
      select top 1 ApproverID
      from steps n
      where s.ProcessID = n.ProcessID
        and s.StepStartDate < n.StepStartDate
      order by n.StepStartDate
    ) n
)
select ProcessID
from nextSteps
group by ProcessID
having sum(disapprove) = 0
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/40a80/6).

Basically for each process step we get the next step in the same process, and check this next step is by the same or a greater approver.

If one or more rows fails, don't return the ProcessID.

**Edit after comment:**

```
with nextSteps as
(
  select s.ProcessID
    , disapprove = case when s.ApproverID = n.ApproverID then 1 else 0 end
  from steps s
    outer apply
    (
      select top 1 ApproverID
      from steps n
      where s.ProcessID = n.ProcessID
        and s.StepStartDate < n.StepStartDate
      order by n.StepStartDate
    ) n
)
select ProcessID
from nextSteps
group by ProcessID
having sum(disapprove) > 0
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3fdce1/2).

This new slightly changed query works for the following approver patterns, as shown in the SQL Fiddle:

**ProcessID 1: A,B,B,C** - Has consecutive approvers, should be returned.

**ProcessID 2: A,B,C,B** - Has no consecutive approvers, should not be returned.

**ProcessID 3: A,B,C,D** - Has no consecutive approvers, should not be returned.

So very similar, checking the next row for each step in a ProcessID, then returning the ProcessID if there is at least one consecutive approver identified.

I've also checked against the data in the SQL Fiddle you added - seems to be working:

[SQL Fiddle with more data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/48589/7).

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but there are 2 things wrong with this.  First, the approver IDs are arbitrary, they will not always be A, B, C , etc, in order.  Second, if I changed processID #2's approvers to A,B,C,D then your query would return it as well - which it should not since there were no 2 consecutive steps approved by the same person.

Comment: @M.Ob, I have slightly changed the query and it seems to be working as required. The extra detail was very helpful in helping clarify the requirements.

Comment: Ian, thank you.  I ended up figuring it out using your query as a starting point.  I will enter my solution as an answer, but will be marking yours as the answer since I wouldn't have figured it out without your help.  Thanks!

Comment: OK, cool! I also just noticed you added a fiddle with more data in the question and double checked the new query against that, too - still looks OK.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with, thanks to Ian's assistance:

```
WITH Steps AS
(
  SELECT
    [CurStep].[ProcessID],
    ConsecutiveApproval =
      CASE
        WHEN [CurStep].[ApproverID] = [NextStep].[ApproverID] THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END
  FROM [Processes] AS CurStep
    OUTER APPLY
    (
      SELECT TOP 1
        [NextStep].[ApproverID]
      FROM
        [Processes] AS NextStep
      WHERE
        [CurStep].[ProcessID] = [NextStep].[ProcessID]
        AND [CurStep].[StepStartDate] < [NextStep].[StepStartDate]
      ORDER BY [NextStep].[StepStartDate]
    ) AS NextStep
)
SELECT   [ProcessID]
FROM     [Steps]
GROUP BY [Steps].[ProcessID]
HAVING   SUM([ConsecutiveApproval]) > 0
```

[Working SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/48589/6)